# Could not resolve dependencies for project Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:jar:4.0.1

Tags: spring, maven-3, netbeans-8

I am using Maven for my project deployment however i am facing the below mentioned error. Can somebody help me out with this. The server used is glassfish.I have included the necessary repositories too. I am not able to find the error.

Failed to execute goal on project cargo-tracker: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.java:cargo-tracker:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:jar:4.0.1.RELEASE in http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release-local was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of org.springframework.maven.release has elapsed or updates are forced

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release-local
```

Use this repository

```
http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release
```